# Opening a socket using a function in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to open a socket in UDP and subsequently send a message using it. This is the code that opens the socket.

```
  sockfd =   startServer(char* ip_addr, int port, struct sockaddr_in server){

        int sockfd, len;

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        if(sockfd < 0){
            perror("Failed to open socket: ");
            exit(-1);
        }

        len = sizeof(server);
        bzero(&server, len);
        server.sin_family= AF_INET;
        inet_aton(ip_addr, &server.sin_addr.s_addr);
        server.sin_port= htons(port);

        if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)) < 0){
            perror("Bind failed: ");
            exit(-1);
        }
        return sockfd;

    }
```

Now to send a message on this socket. I use this function.

```
void sendMessage(char* msg, int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in client, int len){
    int sbytes = 0;

    sbytes = sendto(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, len);

    if(sbytes < 0){
        perror("Error sending message: ");
    }
    printf("Routing vector sent to %s\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
}
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
error: incompatible pointer types passing 'in_addr_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'struct in_addr *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        inet_aton(ip_addr, &server.sin_addr.s_addr);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The first line in your first code block is invalid C syntax - you can't assign the definition of a function to a variable like that (not to mention `sockfd` probably has a type that wouldn't match a function definition, even if you could...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `inet_aton` expects a `struct in_addr *`.  You're passing in `&server.sin_addr.s_addr`, which is an `in_addr_t *`.

What you want is this:

```
inet_aton(ip_addr, &server.sin_addr);
```

Since `server.sin_addr` is a `struct in_addr`.